# UnixODBC driver support in OSX?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, macos, unixodbc

I'm working on a Rails application which I've set up locally on my OSX Machine.  However, the app, which typically runs on a Linux box, connects to a proprietary database via unixODBC.  The database manufacturer only provides drivers for Linux and Windows.  I did some searching around but couldn't figure out what the state of unixODBC is on OSX.  Is there any binary compatibility with Linux drivers, or am I setting up another machine?

Thanks for your time,

-- Henry

Comment: OS X does not provide binary compatibility. Could you mention what the database is?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use Macports to install unixODBC. There are a lot of configuration files to get it going. The binaries will appear under "/opt/local/bin".

Answer (score 3):

iODBC, maintained and supported by [my employer](http://www.openlinksw.com/), has shipped as part of Mac OS X since Jaguar (10.2.x).

You'll be better off [updating iODBC with all the latest patches](http://www.iodbc.org/dataspace/iodbc/wiki/iODBC/Downloads#Mac_OS_X) (Apple tends to be a bit behind on these), than shifting to UnixODBC. You may also find some benefit in the [Ruby+ODBC](http://www.iodbc.org/dataspace/iodbc/wiki/iODBC/IODBCRubyHOWTO#MacOS_X) and [Ruby-on-Rails](http://odbc-rails.rubyforge.org/) docs we've published.

It's generally best to keep all your ODBC configuration in the default file locations for Mac OS X --

```
/Library/ODBC/odbc.ini
/Library/ODBC/odbcinst.ini
/Users/*/Library/ODBC/odbc.ini
/Users/*/Library/ODBC/odbcinst.ini
```

You can create symlinks from anywhere else you may want to have these files, e.g. --

```
ln -s ~/Library/ODBC/odbc.ini ~/.odbc.ini
```

Without knowing the target DBMS, it's impossible to point you to any DBMS-specific ODBC drivers for Mac OS X.  However, my employer does offer a [cross-platform Multi-Tier ODBC Bridge solution](http://uda.openlinksw.com/odbc-odbc-mt/), which will let Mac OS X client applications connect through ODBC drivers on Windows or Linux.